# Parsing a text for finding java method call

Tags: java, parsing

I have a Java source file. I want to parse it to find where a method call occurs. For example, it could find the call:
       obj.callingMethod1(); 
I also want to be able to replace with a different call. For example, I might replace it with:
       obj2.callingMethod2();
but every things are dynamic it means that some where maybe we have a method call with parameter and so on. I found lots of parser for java , but i want to know if there is any parser that has wrote for java grammar ? I mean does it has ability to find java method call , java method definition ,java variable definition and ... thanks     However, I would like to know a way to do this that takes into account the dynamic possibilities for different method calls, i.e. there may be a method call with parameter, etc. I found many Java parsers, but I want to know if there is any parser specifically for Java grammar. I am looking for something that has the ability to find java method calls, java method definitions, java variable definitions, and so on.

Comment: AA parser for Java is written for the Java grammar. A parser outputs a syntax tree in which there is information about the various statements, declarations, etc. of the source being parsed. A parser that cannot differentiate and/or provide information about those would be utterly pointless.

Comment: As you know there are lots of parsers for java ,
the best way is to use this link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators to compare parsers with each other and find which one is more suitable for you .

Comment: Why do you not use just an IDE's services for refactoring? Are your sources not compilable? (BTW: Here is an antlr4 grammar for Java8: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/Java8.g4)

Comment: @GáborBakos I don't want to just refactor name of them , i want to find all methods call and change them to other things for example an if else statement, thanks for introducing antlr4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't explain if the java code occurs within the text or if the text is java code.

Based on what you said it could be

1) There's text and java code and there's a demarcation between text and java code
2) There's text and java code and there is not a demarcation.
3) The text is java code.

If what you need is (1) or (3) then I would use JavaCC: http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf

If what you need is (2) then there isn't much you can do beyond `String.replaceAll(...)`

Comment: thanks for your answer.yes you are right , my text is java code and as you said I need something like javacc.
but I want to know if is there any parser that can help me more to find methods call easier than a parser like javacc or antlr4 or ...